# Creating a matrix of arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create a matrix with elements that are arrays in tensorflow

Assume that I want to create a matrix of size `(2, 2*N)` (in tensorflow) where N is the size of some arrays I have, say

```
a=[1,2,3,..N],
b=2*[1,2,3,..N],
c=3*[1,2,3,..N], 
d=4*[1,2,3,..N]
```

I want to create a matrix `M` such that `M=[[a,b],[c,d]]` through a for loop that inserts the arrays in the matrix.

Is that possible in tensorflow ?

I have tried to write it explicitly as `M=[[a,b],[c,d]]`
and this works, but I want to do it in a for loop and try to insert each array by once.

So could something like this be used inside the loop?

```
M[0,0]=a
M[0,1]=b
M[1,0]=c
M[1,1]=d
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `zip` on the input array with different staggered ranges:

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]

print([[a, b] for a, b in zip(data[::2], data[1::2])])

>>> [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]
```

If you wanted to make it more generic, you could create the input to zip with a comprehension as well, and pass the output of zip iterations to the list constructor:

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]

n = 3

print([list(z) for z in zip(*[data[i::n] for i in range(n)])])

>>> [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]]]
```